# Writing to an output file using fstream in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Assuming you have the proper headers and are using namespace std; is this somewhat correct in terms of using fstream to output a string to some output file? I only included the relevant file API parts of my code as the entirety of it was too long. I've included the iostream and fstream headers. However I seem to get some particular errors, with the way im using the myfile class or object.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "fmttime.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>                      // Needed for the file API
#include <iostream>                     // File API headers for C++
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Enumeration list for the colors of the grid, title, sin and cos waves
enum colors
{
        Gridcolor = 1,
        Titlecolor,
        Sincolor,
        Coscolor,
};

void Sim_Advance(int degrees);          // Function prototype for Phase angle
double Sim_Cos();                       // Function that calculates cos
double Sim_Sin();                       // Function that calculates Sin
char* usage();                          // Function which returns error mssg
static const double PI = (M_PI/180);    // Degrees to radian factor
static double PA = 0;                   // Phase angle
static double x;                        // X dimension of screen
static double y;                        // Y dimension of screen
static int delay1 = 300000;             // 300ms Delay
static int currenty = 0;                // Y index
static const int buffsize = 25;         // Size of the character buffer for time

// Function prototype for frame of plot function
void frame(const char* title, int gridcolor, int labelcolor);

// Function prototype for the symbols that form the plot
void mark(WINDOW* window, char ch, int color, double value);

int main(
        int argc,                       // Number of command line arguements
        char* argv[]                    // String of each command line
        )

{
    initscr();                          // Curses.h initilizations
    cbreak();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();                           // Supress character inputs on screen
    start_color();                      // Enable Bg/Fg colors

    // Color Initializations for the enumeration list

    init_pair(Gridcolor, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(Titlecolor, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(Sincolor, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(Coscolor, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_BLACK);


    int keyhit;                         // Holder for the getch command
    int ctr = 1;                        // Exit flag
    int degrees = 10;                   // Interval to be added to phase
    int enablelog = 0;                  // Flag for Logging enable
    int disabletrunc = 0;               // Flag for logging without truncation
    char* outputName = NULL;            // Name of output program

    FILE* pLog;                         // File pointer for O/P write
    getmaxyx(stdscr,y,x);               // Find max x and y values of stdscrn

    // Defining a new window in the terminal for printing the plot

    WINDOW* Window = newwin(y-4, x, 2, 0);

    x = x - 2 - buffsize;               // Move window to allow for timestamp
    scrollok(Window, TRUE);             // Enable scrolling window

    // Title string for the plotter

    char cTitle[] = {"Real time Sine/ Cosine Plot"};

    //  API Code for FILE output
    ofstream myfile (pLog);             //
    int i = 1;                          // Index for how many times getopt needs
                                        // to be called. Starts at 1 to offset
                                        // program call string, without options
    while (i < argc)
    {
        switch (getopt (argc, argv, "ao:"))
        {
                case 'a':
                disabletrunc = 1;
                break;

                case 'o':
                enablelog = 1;
                outputName = optarg;    // Gets the name of textfile

                // Open the file as designated by the user
                // and assign it to the file pointer pLog
                // The following if else statement opens the file for
                // logging in 2 distinct modes, extended and truncation

                if (disabletrunc == 1)
                {
                    pLog = myfile.open (outputName, ios::out | ios::app);
                }
                else
                {

                // Print with truncation

                    pLog = myfile.open (outputName, ios::out | ios::trunc);
                }

                break;

                // Case of error, print usage message

                case '?':
                endwin();
                puts(usage());
                return 0;

                break;

                // No more options on command line

                case -1:
                i = argc;
                break;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // If only '-a' is enabled then this is still an error case
    // This if statement handles that case

    if (disabletrunc == 1 && enablelog == 0)
    {
        endwin();
        puts("\nWARNING: -a must be used in conjuction with -o FILENAME");
        puts(usage());
        return 0;
    }


        while (ctr == 1)                // This will run the program till
        {                               // exit is detected (CTRL-X)
            usleep(300000);             // Delays program execution
            keyhit = getch();

            frame(cTitle, Gridcolor, Titlecolor);  // Prints out the frame once
           struct timeval tv;
            char buf[buffsize];                    // Buffer being sent to formattime
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);               // calling function for epoch time
            formatTime(&tv, buf, buffsize);        // Calling formaTime for timestamp
            wattrset(Window, COLOR_PAIR(Gridcolor));
            wprintw(Window,"%s", buf);
            wrefresh(Window);

            mark(Window,'|', Gridcolor, 0);
            mark(Window,'C', Coscolor, Sim_Cos());
            mark(Window,'S', Sincolor, Sim_Sin());

            // Scroll to next y coordinate

            wmove(Window, currenty, buffsize + x);
            wrefresh(Window);
            wprintw(Window, "\n");
            wrefresh(Window);

            currenty = getcury(Window);


            // Print desired data into the output file

            if (enablelog == 1)
                myfile << buf << Sim_Sin() << Sim_Cos() << endl;
                //fprintf(pLog, "%s, %f, %f\n", buf, Sim_Sin(), Sim_Cos());

            Sim_Advance(degrees);       // Advances PA by "degrees" value (10)


                if (keyhit == 24)
                {
                    ctr = 0;            // Exit flag set
                }

        }

        // Only close the file if file exists to avoid error
        if (enablelog == 1)
        {
            myfile.close(pLog);
            //close(pLog);
        }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}

// This function will provide an usage message and give the user
// a list of acceptable option characters to use with the program
// when a non valid option character is used or used improperly

char* usage()
{
    // String to be printed as the error message

    static char errors[] = {"\nSorry Invalid Option entered\n\n"
                            "Please Enter a Valid Option specifier:\n"
                            "-o FILENAME      Enable logging to specified "
                            "output file: FILENAME\n"
                            "-a          Enable extended logging"
                            " rather than truncated logging\n\n"
                            "Please Note: -a cannot be used without -o"
                            " FILENAME\n"};

    return errors;
}
```

and then to print it to the file can i do this?

```
myfile << buf << Sim_Sin() << Sim_Cos() << endl;
myfile.close(pLog);
```

Sim_Sin() and Sim_Cos() return double values, and buf is just a formatted string. I tried to apply some of the resources on the internet however it doesn't seem to agree with my implementation (which is obviously wrong).

Here are the errors

```
plot.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
plot.cc:93: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(FILE*&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:623: note: candidates are: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:608: note:                 std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:84: note:                 std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
plot.cc:117: error: expected ';' before 'pLog'
plot.cc:124: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
plot.cc:208: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::close(FILE*&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:736: note: candidates are: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::close() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Comment: 1) What errors are you getting? 2) Can you post a minimal complete example?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I will post the complete code then. I just didnt want someone to read through all of it :S

Comment: I said **minimal!** When you are trying to use an unfamiliar technique (like file I/O) you should try it in isolation first, not graft it into the middle of a huge function.

Comment: I've already done the file API in C, however I need to port it over to C++ now. I assumed it would be an easy task how wrong i was!

Comment: I actually don't think I need the pLog there....just the Outputname arguement....

Comment: The first error is about the fact that you use a `FILE *` (called `pLog`) to initialise the `std::ofstream`. If the plan is to open a file for writing, pass the filename you want (as `const char *`) instead of a `FILE *`, and get rid of `pLog` altogether.

Comment: Thank you I jus realized that. Been coding all day and my brain is on its last legs.

Comment: Good grief! Which of those errors are you having trouble fixing? Did you have compiler warnings with the C code? Which errors appeared when you tried compiling the C code as C++? And why did you keep modifying the code after the first new error appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly *not* correct.

For the moment, I'm going to ignore other issues, and *only* address the writing itself. The most obvious problem with the writing itself is that you almost always want *something* to separate one value from the next. It can be a space, a comma, a tab, a new-line, ..., but you pretty much need something. Without that, it'll be essentially impossible to figure out which digits belong to which number -- for example: `1234.56789.876`

So, when writing out the data, you want to put something recognizable between the pieces of information:

```
myfile << buf << "\t" << Sim_Sin() << "\t" <<  Sim_Cos() << endl;
```

Second, `endl` is *almost* never desirable. Many (most?) think of it as only adding a new-line to the output, but it also *flushes* the stream. As long as you're only writing a line or two of data, that probably doesn't matter, but if you're writing much data, it can slow your code down tremendously.

```
myfile << buf << "\t" << Sim_Sin() << "\t" <<  Sim_Cos() << "\n";
```

In the relatively rare case that you really want to flush the stream, I'd advise using `std::flush` to make that intent clear.

Edit: After your edit, it appears that you're also trying to mix iostreams with C-style `FILE *`s (for example, attempting to open a stream, but supplying a C-style `FILE *` as the parameter). I'd generally advise picking either C-style `FILE *`s (if you have no choice) or iostreams (if possible) and sticking to that one throughout. Mixing the two like you're doing can lead not only to a lot of confusion, but can also slow down your code in some cases (extra time to keep the two coordinated).

```
std::ofstream myfile("name.txt");
myfile << buf << "\t" << Sim_Sin() << "\t" <<  Sim_Cos() << "\n";
```

Comment: I plan to use iostreams, so I realize that i have to rid myself of pLog and just pass the character string file name.